# Server can't find file 'will_paginate' after will_paginate gem installed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, file, rubygems, will-paginate

I have `gem 'will_paginate', '~> 3.0.6'` installed on my app. But when I add the code

```
//= require will_paginate
```

into my `application.js` and try to load a page, I get the following error:

```
Couldn't find file 'will_paginate'
```

Does anyone know why my server might not be able to find the file?

Comment: Why you requiring it as js file????

Comment: https://github.com/mislav/will_paginate

Comment: @rubykid As I remember it, that's what I've had to do with every gem I've ever installed. It also says to here: https://github.com/mislav/will_paginate/wiki/Installation

Comment: My advice: add gem reference to Gemfile, run `bundle install` and be happy

Comment: @rubykid Does will_paginate work for you without requiring the js file?

Comment: I just take a look at source of this gem, there is no js files at all! ))) what you try to to require? The gem itself is just a ruby gem, without any reference to js

Comment: Look, application.js is the manifest for js files, you should place here references to your js scripts that you want to include

Comment: @rubykid Oh sorry, you're right, it's not a js file, it's an rb file. Does the gem work for you without requiring any files at all?

Comment: To be honest I have used it a long time ago, but I'm sure that there you don't need such kind of requiring. Just follow instructions on gem's main page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, your Application.js has this line:

//= require will_paginate

When the app launches it looks for the listed JavaScript files/libraries to be available. will_paginate.js doesn't exist, so app errors out on load.

"will_paginate" is a gem, so I think rubykid is right--bundle all. The next step is make sure all the .paginate hooks are in all the right places in the controllers and views. But you didn't ask about that, so I won't go there.

Good luck.